# Split byte array by certain byte (character)

Tags: java

I am building history parser, there's an application that already done the logging task (text based).
Now that my supervisor want me to create an application to read that log.
The log is is created at the end of the month, and is separated by [date]:

[19-11-2014]
- what goes here
- what goes here

[20-11-2014]
- what goes here
- what goes here

etc...

If the log file has small size, there's no problem processing the content by DataInputStream to get the byte[], and convert it to String and then do the filtering process (by doing substring and such).

But when the file has a large size (about 100mb), it throws JavaHeapSpace exception. I know that this is because the length of the content exceeds String maxlength, when I try not to convert the byte[] into string, no exception was thrown.

Now the question is, how do I split the byte[] into several byte[]?
Which is each new byte[] only contains single:

[date]
- what goes here

So if within a month we have 9 dates in log, it would be split into 9 byte[].
The splitting marker would be based on [\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}] , if it is string I could just use Regex to find all the marker, get the indexOf and then substring it.

But how do I do this without converting to string first? As it would throws the JavaHeapSpace.

Comment: Can you modify the application doing the logging task? If so, what logging suystem does it use?

Comment: Can you use partial parsing with some buffer with fixed size? I mean you can read for example 1024 bytes and then read next 1024 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several concepts here that you're missing.

First, an `InputStream` is a Stream, which means it is a flow of bytes. What you do with that flow is up to you, but saving all of the stream to memory defies the point of the stream construct altogether.

Second, a `DataInputStream` is used to read objects from a binary file that were serialized there by a `DataOutputStream`. Reading just a string is overkill for this type of Stream, since a simple `InputStream` can do that.

As for your specific problem, I would use a BufferedFileReader, and read one line at a time, until reaching the next date. At that point you can do whatever processing you need on the last chunk of lines you read, and free the memory. Thus not running into the same problem.